# Possible memory leaks on inner final object (Java)

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I have searched through these occasions a little bit and couldn't find a satisfying answer, so here I am. **Note:** This is going to be an example code, as I cannot post anything from the original code since it is classified.

Suppose this occasion:

```
public class Instance
{
    private ClassMember classMember = new ClassMember();

    // Imagine this method is called once as like the main method of apps.
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Instance().myMethod();
    }

    private void myMethod()
    {
        final SomeObject object = new SomeObject();

        // This is the class member that is declared at top of the class.
        classMember.addCallback(new Callback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCall(boolean result)
            {
                object.setResult(result).report(); // I'm done with this object, want to release it.

                // After this call, will there be a leak due to "SomeObject object"?
                // If so, how can this be prevented from happening?
            }
        });

        object.makeCall(classMember); // asynchronous task such as Internet connections.
    }
}
```

Let's explain variables and classes:

- Instance is the supposedly main class that contains the main method. Consider this method as called from another class, this is defined for simplicity.
- ClassMember is a class that handles internet connection callbacks. Will be used with **SomeObject**.
- SomeObject is an object that has to be instantiated in the method as final, to use inside the "addCallback" method. "makeCall" method is asynchronous that may be finished or not, such as making Internet connections.

Now, what I wonder is, there might be a memory leak due to "final SomeObject object" and I want to prevent it by releasing it after receiving the callback at "onCall()" method, such as setting it to null. But because it is final, I cannot do that, hence I'm looking for an alternative.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Why not simply create the object in the `onCall` method?

Comment: onCall method is a callback that is executed via "object.makeCall" so I cannot create it inside.

Comment: You are not removing the callback?

Comment: "so I cannot create it inside" => I don't see any reasons against! Simply do `new SomeObject().setResult(result).report()`.

Comment: There are methods that I can remove the callback, but I'm worried about "SomeObject object" itself because "classMember" is global.

Comment: That one is not a problem - the only possible problem is the reference from `classMember` via the callback (unless one of the methods does something unexpected, like handing a reference to the result/report or something).

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose That might be a way to solve it, but due to asynchronous call I don't think the object will be garbage collected anyway, right?

Comment: @FurkanYurdakul it will, when it is no longer reachable - if it only exists as a local variable in the callback itself, it becomes eligible for collection as soon as that method returns.

Comment: @Hulk So simply I need to remove the callback once the task is complete in some way. After that I have nothing to worry for.

Comment: @FurkanYurdakul at least not from the code you've shown here ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the provided code there is no memory leak due to `someObject` it being `final` or not. The instance is only used within the scope of `myMethod` and no reference is given to the outside (at least outside of `Instance`). That is the GC will notice that it can be collected after `myMethod` or the asynchronous `makeCall` have finished.

The only thing I‘m worried about is that you mention the call to `makeCall` might not finish at all. You have to keep in mind that all resources in the context of this call will be uncollectable until the call has finished. That is the instances of `Instance`, `ClassMember` and `SomeObject` will remain on the heap for the duration of `makeCall`.

Of course if you do something stupid in `makeCall` you will get a leak the one way or the other.


**UPDATE:**


As @Seelenvirtuose pointed out your example code may be a little oversimplified, resulting to false assumptions being made. My answer is correct as long as the instances of `Instance` are used in the way they are used in the provided code - as one-shot-obects. You have to be aware that with each call to `myMethod` and each call to `classMember.addCallback`, `classMember` will get a reference to the `object` instance created in `myMethod`. That is references to `object` will accumulate in `classMember` and thus in the respective instance of `Instance` - that's what I meant with my addition *at least outside of `Instance`*. Given the provided code you might end up with a memory leak or not. It all depends on the usage of `Instance` in your real world scenario.

Comment: Okay, so inside the asynchronous call, I can use a timeout to finish the job if it helds until the timeout has reached (such as 10 seconds that happens on most of the internet connections). This approach will prevent the leak for sure then?

Comment: @FurkanYurdakul Yes. Unless - as mentioned - you do something stupid in `makeCall` like storing something in a global state, or similar

Comment: Thank you for leading me to the correct way to do it, I'm marking your answer as the accepted one.

Comment: In the shown code of the question the object _can not_ be garbage collected. This makes this answer wrong. The object is referenced by the instance of the anonymous class, which in turn is added as a call back to an object referenced by an instance member.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose and this object can be garbage collected as soon as the `makeCall` method finished. Perhaps think twice before downvoting and making false claims.

Comment: It _can not_ be garbage collected as soon as the `makeCall` or the `myMethod` method is finished because this object is referenced by the instance member.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose but the instance is only used in the context of this single call `new Instance().myMethod()`. Yes `classMember` holds a reference to `object` but this makes no difference as `classMember` will be unreachable after `makeCall` and the related callback as well. There are some uncertainties as we don’t have the code of  `addCallback` and `makeCall` but given the provided code there should not be a memory leak.

Comment: Man. No. The object referenced by `classMember` is reachable as long the instance of `Instance` exists (or is reachable). This has nothing to do with the execution of the `myMehod` method.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose yes you‘re totally right. But the instance of `Instance` is only created to make the call the `myMethod` it is not stored anywhere. So why should this instance remain reachable?

Comment: The question for garbage collection is totally super-fluous here, because the program exits after the main method and each thread has been terminated. The main method here seems only to be there to demonstrate the problem and have a running example. I think, the real code has no main method here. But if you change your answer to make that clear, I will remove my downvote because then it will be a correct (and good) answer.

Comment: The main problem with your answer is your second sentence: "The instance is only used within the scope of myMethod and no reference is given to the outside". This is wrong, as the instance is still referenced even if the method call to `myMethod` is finished.

Comment: @dpr I'm sorry for not being a bit more specific about how `Instance` is called. It has been called once and not multiple times, there are conditions that checking it. That's why I've tried to simplify it as a one-caller, but it wasn't a good way to do so. But yeah, it is called only once.

Comment: @FurkanYurdakul, the problem is not how often `Instance` is being used but what happens with the instances of `Instance`: `new Instance().myMethod()` -> perfectly fine. `Instance instance = new Instance(); instance.myMethod();` -> depends on what you do with `instance`.

Comment: I'm using the way `new Instance().myMethod()` so I don't think there are problems at that point. Instance is not held in another class or statically.

Comment: @FurkanYurdakulm then you should be fine. However in this context adding callbacks to `classMember` seems like a little overkill. You could simply pass the callback to `makeCall` directly or - even simpler - call `object.setResult(result).report();` from within `makeCall`.

Answer (score -1):

The final state will not prevent it from garbage collection. If the callback is executed and object is not held within classMember (due to some handler list or sth. like this) the reference counter decreases to 0 and thus it will be garbage collected (at some time).

Comment: Unfortunately, this is wrong. This object has a reference in the instance of the anonymous class (`new Callback() { ... }`) which is added to the `ClassMember` instance referenced by `classMember`. So it will not be garbaged collected after execution of the `onCall` method.

Comment: Sure, but only as long as the callback will be retained in `classMember`. That is why I mentioned the handler list.

Comment: OP posted the code. The object is held. So it can't be garbaged collected.